# Как существующего пользователя привязать к другому порталу

Tags: windows, битрикс24, настройка, настройки, crm

Есть пользователь Иван Иванов и портал, к которому он привязан

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как привязать этого пользователя к другому порталу? Прошу не минусовать, я новичок в настройке Битрикс24.

Comment: [Как пригласить сотрудников в Битрикс24](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/17726876/)

Answer (score 1):

смотря какие цели вы преследуете. Если вы в каком-то из порталов работаете как подрядчик то вы со своим аккаунтом работаете через экстранет версию связи порталов. И они у вас в списке порталов будут оба появляться после авторизации. Если у вас несколько версий порталов коробка и облако, можно работать в обоих одновременно через десктоп версию чтобы получать уведомления. Если вас добавили или вы сами создали несколько порталов, вы можете свободно переключаться между ними. Статьи на эту тему есть в ТП поддержки битрикса: 1) [мультипортальность](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/4816797/) , 2) [один е-мэил и пароль на все порталы](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/bitrix24/bitrix-one-email-one-password.php)
выглядит так: [image: список порталов в битрикс.паспорт]

P.s. В итоге привязка работает так: либо вас пригласили в портал. Либо вы подрядчик и тоже приглашены. Либо вы сами создали несколько порталов от своего аккаунта. ссылка на статью про [битрикс.паспорт](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/17672770/)